# React router redux lags one history step behing when router receives state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

Here's a repo with full code demonstrating the problem -
 https://github.com/Misiur/ReactRouterReduxBug

Online - https://codesandbox.io/s/v88B5LG0

Take a look at this code

```
class Main extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.page !== nextProps.match.params.page) {
      console.log(`Page changed to ${nextProps.match.params.page}`);
    } else {
      console.log('Page did not change');
      console.log(newProps.location.pathname);
      console.log(newProps.history.location.pathname);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const page = this.props.match.params.page;

    return (
      <div>
        <strong>Current page is {page}</strong><br />
        <Link to="/1">Page 1</Link><br />
        <Link to="/2">Page 2</Link><br />
        <Link to="/3">Page 3</Link><br />
        <Link to="/4">Page 4</Link><br />
        <Link to="/5">Page 5</Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const RawRouting = (props) => {
  // Do something with this.props.state
  // console.log(props);

  return (
    <Route path="/:page(\d+)?" component={Main} />
  );
};

const Routing = connect(state => ({ state }))(RawRouting);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Routing />
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

We have `App` which scaffolds the store and router, `Routing` which defines routes **and is `connect`ed to the state**, and `Main` component displaying page and links to pages.

When you click on links, all works fine. However when you push browser's back button, first time url changes but the route parameter does not, because `newProps.location.pathname` is one history step behind `newProps.history.location.pathname`.

I've dug deep enough to find out what causes it, but not why: the `connect` on our `Routing`. When it is removed, back button works correctly. That's not the solution as I *need* the state there.

So:

1. How to make back/forward button work **without removing my state mapping**?
2. *Why* is it the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to wrap it in `withRouter`. See https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/redux.md#blocked-updates