# React router takes several seconds to route

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

```
      <Switch>         
        <Route path="/" exact component={Panels}/>           
        <Route path="/settings" component={ImgurPage}/>          
        <Route path="" component={Panels} />
      </Switch>
```

The routing from home to settings page is fine. But when I step back with "this.props.history.goBack()" in the **Settings Page** it takes three seconds before rerouting.

Looking at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451214/react-router-redux-lags-one-history-step-behing-when-router-receives-state) , I've also tried to wrap with **withRouter**, I'm still getting the same issue.

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,{getclientid,getClientSecret,imgurFormSubmit})(ImgurPage))
```

Is redux slowing down my routing?

Edit: I've removed the default case as suggested.Still getting the same issue. Is it an issue with **HashRouter**?

```
    <HashRouter>

        <Switch>

            <Route path="/" exact component={Panels}/>

            <Route path="/settings" component={ImgurPage}/>          

        </Switch>
     </HashRouter>
```

Comment: Ran into a similar issue where I thought the router was just hanging out for a few seconds *then* updating the route, but throwing a log on the new route's `componentDidMount` proved the routing was occurring immediately and it was actually React that was slow/delayed/etc while building out the new DOM.  I ran a performance audit and eventually found we had a typography class of components that took anywhere from 4-6ms to just be created (as opposed to the fractions of a millisecond for most other function calls).  I suggest you try the same to try and narrow down where your bottleneck is.

Comment: It is an issues with functions inside componentDidMount. I'm retrieving a list of data from a file. And it's firing everytime I route

Comment: Ah, yeah, to get around that I actually used a "fake loading" trick to render a loading spinner in order to get to that first render faster.  We were just loading a lot of data from a redux store and building a large list, so any indication to the user that "something" is happening is better than the page looking frozen.  In your case the idiomatic solution is also to store a local loading state (`true`) while you send off your async data request, and when that resolves, set loading to false and render your data.  OFC, other solutions exist to help persist that result.

Comment: Is there a way to make it fetch the data only once when I start the app?

Comment: Yes, several.  The easiest is probably to just loft that data load call closer to the app root, like in your routes component since that likely is mounted once when your app starts.  But page refreshes will cause a remount (and data refetch).  Other solutions involve app state management, like redux. And still more involve persisting data to local storage (reload after refreshes and don't refetch).  It really depends on your needs, but going into more detail here now is a bit out of scope for your question.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need withRouter here. As you are within the Route's Component. You will have the router context already there.

Why do you have `<Route path="" component={Panels} />`. You already have the panels component when user navigates to root. Try removing this line and also withRouter.

Comment: I have removed the line and the withRouter. I'm still getting lag. Please check my edit